# Accessing a Numeric Key in Json Return Using Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel-8

I have a geocoding application that is returning me a large JSON array with tons of values.  I am trying to drill down to one value called Census_Tract.  Right now, I have been able to drill down several levels using the followingin Laravel.

```
dd($response->results[0]->response->results[0]->fields->census);
```

that resurns a small JSON array that looks like this:

```
{#669 ▼
  +"2019": {#666 ▼
    +"census_year": 2019
    +"state_fips": "09"
    +"county_fips": "09001"
    +"tract_code": "100300"
    +"block_code": "1061"
    +"block_group": "1"
    +"full_fips": "090011003001061"
    +"place": null
    +"metro_micro_statistical_area": {#667 ▶}
    +"combined_statistical_area": {#668 ▶}
    +"metropolitan_division": null
    +"source": "US Census Bureau"
  }
}
```

How do I get past the 2019 numeric key?  I keep getting the following error:

```
unexpected integer "2019"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```php
$response= $response->results[0]->response->results[0]->fields->census;
var_dump($response->{'2019'});
```

Comment: Perfect... thank you!